# jQuery click and show list of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have list of elements from DB and show in table with button:

```
<a href="#" class="hiden"></a>
```

for show and hide advance info where contain in

```
<div class="object></div>
```

My jQuery script is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".object").hide();
    $('.hiden').click(function() {
        $(".object").toggle();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th class="but" colspan="2"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($model as $object): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#"><?php echo $object->name; ?></a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="but">
        <a href="#" class="hiden"></a> 
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <div class="object">            
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have some problems when a click on a.hiden all elements of list show and click all elements hide. I want while one element show other elements hide.

Please help me

Comment: Which element should stay while the others hide? Are you trying to do an accordion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".object").hide();
    $('.hiden').click(function() {
        $(this).parents('tr').next().find(".object").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Toogle is right way, but each of your elements must have a unique identifier, if you click on them and trigger an event.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$(".object").toggle();
```

to:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next().find(".object").toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you describe is what you actually coded. Your selector

```
$(".object").toggle()
```

toggles all elements with class `.object`, not just one.
To toggle only the one in the same table row you could

```
$('.hiden').click(function() {
    $(this).parent("tr").next().find(".object").toggle();
});
```